# Where is /etc/nftables/inet-filter?

Tags: vagrant, nftables, netfilter

I am trying to locate the file `/etc/nftables/inet-filter` which is referenced in the readme for a project I've inherited. When I installed nftables, the only files that existed in `etc/nftables` were:

```
.  ..  main.nft  nat.nft  osf  router.nft
```

I found an [inet-filter.nft](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/files/examples/inet-filter.nft?h=v0.8.4) file at git.netfilter.org which consists of:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table inet filter {
    chain input     { type filter hook input priority 0; }
    chain forward       { type filter hook forward priority 0; }
    chain output        { type filter hook output priority 0; }
}
```

but I'm not sure if this is the file that my project was referencing.

If anyone has actually used the `inet-filter.nft` file, does this look familiar? Or is `inet-filter.nft` obsolete for some reason?

Thanks.

Fedora system: `Linux fedora 5.18.11-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 12 22:52:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Vagrant: `Vagrant 2.3.0`

nftables: `nftables v1.0.1 (Fearless Fosdick #3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears they are [not packaged](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nftables/blob/f36/f/nftables.spec#_77) on Fedora since Fedora 36:

> ```
> # drop vendor-provided configs, they are not really useful
> rm -f $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_datadir}/nftables/*.nft
> ```

Instead, a ["more advanced default config" is shipped](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nftables/c/de6fc1c6f7a62c84cc0c9570c7419881a79567b5?branch=f36) with files [`/etc/nftables/main.nft`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nftables/blob/f36/f/main.nft),[`router.nft`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nftables/blob/f36/f/router.nft) and [`nat.nft`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/nftables/blob/f36/f/nat.nft).

> ```
> # Sample configuration for nftables service.
> # Load this by calling 'nft -f /etc/nftables/main.nft'.
> ```

Anyway you should create your own tables, especially considering that having different hook types in the same table (eg filter + nat) is what should be done with *nftables* because separating them would hinder functionality (eg: sharing the same set accross chains with a different type requires them to be in the same table). *nftables*' tables are not an exact equivalent of *iptables*' tables.

If you need this file to follow some example then yes, the file you found is the one you were looking for. For 1.0.1 this file and other related files are found [there](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/files/nftables?h=v1.0.1) instead.